crossed product by compact groups
Do we need the ambient measure on G to be a Haar measure in order to form the crossed product by a compact group of a von Neumann algebra M? If the measure is indeed Haar, then we can obtain the crossed product as the fixed point of the action of $\theta_g:=\alpha_g \otimes Ad \lambda_g$ on $M \otimes B(L^{2}(G))$ . What can we conclude if the measure is not Haar, but instead any finite measure?

You certainly can write down the definition of such an object, but it’s not going to be naturally isomorphic to the usual crossed product, nor is it clear to me why you would want to define such an object though.

This is because when you take Haar measure you can identify the crossed product as fixed point algebra of $(M \otimes B(L^2(G))^{\theta}$. In particular, for reference look at van daele book.

Isn’t the question here about what happens when the measure is not Haar? I know what happens for the Haar measure case.

Yes, the question is edited

I’m confused. I don’t see any new question here. Is the question about whether you can construct crossed product with a measure that’s not Haar (you can - I already mentioned in the comments) or specifically about what happens to $\theta$ (in that case you should write down the definition of $\theta$ - I’m reasonably sure what it is, but you might have something else in mind)?

$\theta_g=\alpha_g \otimes Ad_{\lambda_g}$

I was more trying to ask whether your aim is to know whether the crossed product can be constructed or whether $\theta$ works, not just what $\theta$ is… Regardless, since you gave the definition of $\theta$, I’ll assume you want to know whether $\theta$ works. In that case, no. In the worst case, $\lambda_g$ can be ill-defined altogether if $g_\ast \mu$ is not equivalent to $\mu$. (I was implicitly assuming this is not the case when I said you can still construct the crossed product, as there really is no way to get around $\lambda_g$ being ill-defined.) Even if $g_\ast \mu$ is equivalent to…

… $\mu$ for all $g$, $\lambda_g$ can still be unbounded, so $\text{Ad}{\lambda_g}$ may not be everywhere defined on $B(L^2(G))$. Even if $\lambda_g$ are bounded for all $g$, unless $\mu$ is Haar, $\lambda_g$ are not going to be unitaries for $g$, so $\text{Ad}{\lambda_g}(x) = \lambda_g x (\lambda_g)^{-1}$ are no longer $\ast$-automorphisms. Thus, the fixed point algebra of $\theta$ is no longer necessarily a $\ast$-algebra, let along a von Neumann algebra. So, no, if you want to construct crossed products using a non-Haar measure (I still have no idea why you would want to do that), using…

… $\theta$ will not work. Instead, just use the more common construction of crossed products, as a subalgebra of $B(L^2(G) \otimes L^2(M))$. The definition still works basically as is, insofar as $\lambda_g$ are all well-defined. (You don’t even need them to be bounded, as you can just decompose into their polar parts and spectral projections of their absolute values.)

Basically if it is Haar then you know the $\int \alpha_g(m) d\mu$ in the $M^G$, where $\alpha$ is the action, what can you say if the measure is not Haar, where this integral will belong? I know it is obviously in M, but can you say something concrete

In general, no. There needs to be constraints on either $m$, or $\mu$, or $\alpha$.

What if M is type III and alpha is outer?

No. In the extreme case just take $\mu$ to be the Dirac delta at ${e}$, then whatever $M$ or $\alpha$ is doesn’t even matter, your integral is always going to be just $m$.
